# How to smooth collapse effect for collapse impacted element in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a collapsible layout using Bootstrap 3.

The problem is the `impacted-element` doesn't have a smooth move-down effect like the move-up.

How can I make it move down slowly like move up?

Here is my code: (Please review in full page)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Two Column Layout with Background Image and Expand</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <style>
      .first-column {
        background-image: url("https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1688114984765-308599ec1e13?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80");
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 300px;
        transition-duration: 0.35s;
      }
      .second-column {
        min-height: 300px;
      }
      .expanded {
        min-height: 500px;
      }
      .impacted-element {
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
      }

      .impacted-element.collapsed {
        max-height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 first-column"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6 second-column">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut interdum
            purus vel mauris ultrices, ac tincidunt risus interdum. Aenean at
            feugiat arcu. Nunc consectetur, nisi id venenatis suscipit, odio
            ipsum tincidunt ipsum, eu bibendum turpis lorem vel orci. In eu mi
            semper, varius quam nec, mattis odio. Vivamus venenatis odio nec
            libero egestas tincidunt. Nulla et sagittis mi, ut congue odio. Nam
            blandit mauris vitae lectus euismod, nec fermentum neque mattis.
          </p>
          <button id="expandBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Expand</button>
          <div id="expandedContent" style="display: none;">
            <p>
              Pellentesque id tortor ipsum. Vivamus vitae ligula a massa
              vestibulum scelerisque. Duis congue eros a quam tincidunt, eu
              elementum sem eleifend. Proin suscipit, elit a sagittis laoreet,
              libero lectus fermentum nisl, quis gravida elit massa id elit.
              Fusce tristique, sem id iaculis consectetur, est nunc aliquam
              massa, id consectetur lorem odio sit amet neque. Proin elementum
              euismod varius. Nam laoreet odio eu elit dapibus vehicula. Integer
              ultricies lacus vel tristique finibus.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="impacted-element">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut interdum
          purus vel mauris ultrices, ac tincidunt risus interdum. Aenean at
          feugiat arcu. Nunc consectetur, nisi id venenatis suscipit, odio ipsum
          tincidunt ipsum, eu bibendum turpis lorem vel orci. In eu mi semper,
          varius quam nec, mattis odio. Vivamus venenatis odio nec libero
          egestas tincidunt. Nulla et sagittis mi, ut congue odio. Nam blandit
          mauris vitae lectus euismod, nec fermentum neque mattis.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#expandBtn").click(function () {
          $("#expandedContent").slideToggle();
          $(".first-column, .second-column").toggleClass("expanded");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add `transition: all 0.3s ease;` also to `.second-column`. Please note that you are not utilizing bootstrap's [collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp) built in support. Instead you're using css (which is ok) and jQuery "propriety" `slideToggle`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Two Column Layout with Background Image and Expand</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <style>
      .first-column {
        background-image: url("https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1688114984765-308599ec1e13?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80");
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 300px;
        transition-duration: 0.35s;
      }
      .second-column {
        min-height: 300px;
        transition-duration: 0.35s;
      }
      .expanded {
        min-height: 500px;
      }
      .impacted-element {
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
      }

      .impacted-element.collapsed {
        max-height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 first-column"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6 second-column">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut interdum
            purus vel mauris ultrices, ac tincidunt risus interdum. Aenean at
            feugiat arcu. Nunc consectetur, nisi id venenatis suscipit, odio
            ipsum tincidunt ipsum, eu bibendum turpis lorem vel orci. In eu mi
            semper, varius quam nec, mattis odio. Vivamus venenatis odio nec
            libero egestas tincidunt. Nulla et sagittis mi, ut congue odio. Nam
            blandit mauris vitae lectus euismod, nec fermentum neque mattis.
          </p>
          <button id="expandBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Expand</button>
          <div id="expandedContent" style="display: none;">
            <p>
              Pellentesque id tortor ipsum. Vivamus vitae ligula a massa
              vestibulum scelerisque. Duis congue eros a quam tincidunt, eu
              elementum sem eleifend. Proin suscipit, elit a sagittis laoreet,
              libero lectus fermentum nisl, quis gravida elit massa id elit.
              Fusce tristique, sem id iaculis consectetur, est nunc aliquam
              massa, id consectetur lorem odio sit amet neque. Proin elementum
              euismod varius. Nam laoreet odio eu elit dapibus vehicula. Integer
              ultricies lacus vel tristique finibus.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="impacted-element">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut interdum
          purus vel mauris ultrices, ac tincidunt risus interdum. Aenean at
          feugiat arcu. Nunc consectetur, nisi id venenatis suscipit, odio ipsum
          tincidunt ipsum, eu bibendum turpis lorem vel orci. In eu mi semper,
          varius quam nec, mattis odio. Vivamus venenatis odio nec libero
          egestas tincidunt. Nulla et sagittis mi, ut congue odio. Nam blandit
          mauris vitae lectus euismod, nec fermentum neque mattis.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#expandBtn").click(function () {
          $("#expandedContent").slideToggle();
          $(".first-column, .second-column").toggleClass("expanded");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```